# BeautifulSoup scraping pactpub html element returns empty item

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape the following

```html
<li class="ais-pagination--item ais-pagination--item__next">
```

tag from https://www.packtpub.com/all-products/all-books which represent the next page button

using the following code:

```
import requests
import re
import bs4


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
start_url="https://www.packtpub.com/all-products/all-books"
req = requests.get(start_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
next_page_li = soup.find("li", class_="ais-pagination--item ais-pagination--item__next")
```

I get **None** in return, please help.

Comment: since you are dealing with a dynamic `JavaScript` website, so you've to render it or to use real browser such as `selenium`, but to make your life easier, you can call the back-end `API` directly which is [here](https://vivzzxfqg1-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.0;instantsearch.js%202.10.2;Magento2%20integration%20(1.13.3);JS%20Helper%202.26.0&x-algolia-application-id=VIVZZXFQG1&x-algolia-api-key=MjBiNTIwZWM0MmE4MWQ0MDQwNzIxY2Q5ZTQ0ZjE0ZDNkMzI4ZDVkZWJiYzcxNGI1NjA2MWYzNmUyNTQxY2ViZnRhZ0ZpbHRlcnM9)

Comment: thanks, how can I know if a website is a dynamic Javascript?

Comment: You welcome. simply, you can view page source and locate the element within it, if it's there so it's static, if not, so it's just a dynamic object. *note that inspecting the element directly will lead to view it whatever it's dynamic or static* but usually you will notice an `even` flag beside the dynamic object. BTW, am coding currently for calling the back end API.

Comment: great - you did a great job! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind that, You are dealing with a website which it's content is loaded dynamically once the page loads via an [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) `POST` request to the following back-end [API](https://vivzzxfqg1-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.0%3Binstantsearch.js%202.10.2%3BMagento2%20integration%20(1.13.3)%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0&x-algolia-application-id=VIVZZXFQG1&x-algolia-api-key=MjBiNTIwZWM0MmE4MWQ0MDQwNzIxY2Q5ZTQ0ZjE0ZDNkMzI4ZDVkZWJiYzcxNGI1NjA2MWYzNmUyNTQxY2ViZnRhZ0ZpbHRlcnM9) which loads a `JSON` data.

So in order to verify if the website content is dynamic or static, you've to view the page source and search for the desired element, if it's there, so it's a static content, if not so you are dealing with dynamic objects which you've to trace from where it's obtained.

> Note that viewing page source is different than inspecting the element directly. as inspecting the element will view it in both cases. but you will notice that any dynamic content will be holding an `event` flag beside it.

Below is a direct call to the `API`, in case if you would like to loop over the result, Then you have to play with `hitsPerPage` which can obtain up to `1000` per call. and then you've to loop over the pages. since the website contain `5660` so you've to loop in `range(6)` because the pagination for that site starting from `0`.

```
import requests


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:

        params = {
            "x-algolia-agent": "Algolia for vanilla JavaScript (lite) 3.27.0;instantsearch.js 2.10.2;Magento2 integration (1.13.3);JS Helper 2.26.0",
            "x-algolia-application-id": "VIVZZXFQG1",
            "x-algolia-api-key": "MjBiNTIwZWM0MmE4MWQ0MDQwNzIxY2Q5ZTQ0ZjE0ZDNkMzI4ZDVkZWJiYzcxNGI1NjA2MWYzNmUyNTQxY2ViZnRhZ0ZpbHRlcnM9"
        }

        data = {"requests": [{"indexName": "store_prod_us_products_packt_rank_asc", "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=24&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&ruleContexts=%5B%22%22%2C%22magento-category-7164%22%5D&clickAnalytics=true&facets=%5B%22product_type_filter%22%2C%22released%22%2C%22language%22%2C%22concept%22%2C%22tool%22%2C%22vendor%22%2C%22categories.level0%22%2C%22categories.level1%22%2C%22categories.level2%22%2C%22categories.level0%22%2C%22categories.level1%22%2C%22categories.level2%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22released%3AAvailable%22%5D%2C%5B%22categories.level1%3AAll%20Products%20%2F%2F%2F%20All%20Books%22%5D%5D&numericFilters=%5B%22visibility_catalog%3D1%22%5D"}, {"indexName": "store_prod_us_products_packt_rank_asc", "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=1&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&ruleContexts=%5B%22%22%2C%22magento-category-7164%22%5D&clickAnalytics=false&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&facets=released&numericFilters=%5B%22visibility_catalog%3D1%22%5D&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22categories.level1%3AAll%20Products%20%2F%2F%2F%20All%20Books%22%5D%5D"}, {
            "indexName": "store_prod_us_products_packt_rank_asc", "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=1&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&ruleContexts=%5B%22%22%2C%22magento-category-7164%22%5D&clickAnalytics=false&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&facets=%5B%22categories.level0%22%2C%22categories.level1%22%5D&numericFilters=%5B%22visibility_catalog%3D1%22%5D&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22released%3AAvailable%22%5D%2C%5B%22categories.level0%3AAll%20Products%22%5D%5D"}, {"indexName": "store_prod_us_products_packt_rank_asc", "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=1&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&ruleContexts=%5B%22%22%2C%22magento-category-7164%22%5D&clickAnalytics=false&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&facets=%5B%22categories.level0%22%5D&numericFilters=%5B%22visibility_catalog%3D1%22%5D&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22released%3AAvailable%22%5D%5D"}]}
        r = req.post(url, params=params, json=data).json()
        for x in r['results'][0]['hits']:
            print(x['name'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://vivzzxfqg1-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries')
```

Output:

```
C# 9 and .NET 5 – Modern Cross-Platform Development - Fifth Edition
40 Algorithms Every Programmer Should Know
Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading - Second Edition
Learning C# by Developing Games with Unity 2020 - Fifth Edition
Solutions Architect's Handbook
Python Machine Learning - Third Edition
The Python Workshop
Kubernetes and Docker - An Enterprise Guide
Django 3 By Example - Third Edition
Full-Stack React, TypeScript, and Node
Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS - Third Edition
Learn Python Programming - Second Edition
CompTIA Security+: SY0-601 Certification Guide - Second Edition
Hands-On Quantum Information Processing with Python
Node.js Design Patterns - Third Edition
ASP.NET Core 5 for Beginners
Learning Tableau 2020 - Fourth Edition
AWS Penetration Testing
Python 3 Object-Oriented Programming - Third Edition
Hands-On Unity 2020 Game Development
Software Architecture with C# 9 and .NET 5 - Second Edition
Mastering Blockchain - Third Edition
The Docker Workshop
Data Engineering with Python
```

Comment: many thanks for sharing your ideas, knowledge and insights with us. The solution looks awesome - a great solution and a nice solving ot the problem. Thanks to you!!!